# Retrieve all child records based on parent with Laravel 4 and mySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm getting to know Laravel and Eloquent and it's very powerful. I can't seem to figure out the following however. Here's my database structure:

```
Companies--Projects--Blocks<-user_block->Users
```

`So a company hasMany Projects
Project belongsTo a Company
A Project hasMany Blocks
A Block belongsTo a Project
Users belongsToMany Blocks
Blocks belongsToMany Users`

(many-to-many between users and blocks using a pivot table).

I want to pull up all users who are part of a project. I have no problem pulling up all users who are part of a block, but to work my way up one level - how can I do this?

In my MessageController I was doing the following:

    `$users = User::with('blocks')
    ->where('company_id','=',3)
    ->orderBy('lastname','asc')
    ->get();`

Somehow I want to pass the project id to my query and retrieve only those users who are in any block which belongs to that project (which I then use to send a message).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found an answer:

`$users = User::select('users.id as user_id', 'users.email as email')
      ->distinct()
      ->join('user_block', 'users.id', '=', 'user_block.user_id')
      ->join('blocks', 'user_block.block_id', '=', 'blocks.id')
      ->where('blocks.project_id','=',$project_id)
      ->get();`

where I pass the project_id to limit the records returned.

I'm still able to access the model in the blade template to call a function which checks which users have uploaded all the required documents for each block.